# Mutual information between a vector of values and a statistic computed on the vector

Tags: entropy, mutual-information

I understand that the mutual information between two vectors X, Y from two distributions  gives a measure of uncertainty of X knowing information about Y. But is it possible to measure mutual information between a vector X and its mean E(X)? Is there a way to do it using R?